# iOS 13 - UITextField with Placeholder getting app crash

Tags: uitextfield, ios13, placeholder

In iOS 13, I'm getting a crash when accessing the `UITextField` _placeholderLabel.textColor label key.

The key used to apply placeholder text color.

```
[textfield setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

> "NSGenericException" - reason: "Access to UITextField's _placeholderLabel ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug"

Comment: This issue exists in **Xcode 11 GM seed** too.

Comment: @SunilTarge check answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56776561/3560390

Comment: This isn't an "issue". Poking at internal implementation details is not allowed. You are violating App Store guidelines. Any "workaround" you attempt will be broken again soon. Stop.

Comment: @PrasathBabu this freeze is only for simulator right ? as long as in the real device is not freezing then it is not an issue ? I am a beginner. I am confused because I don't have this freezing on real device but only in simulator. so if I don't care about simulator, I don't need to add the answers below right ? please really need your info

Comment: @Alexa289 Crash happens on the device - when you build an app with Xcode11 and iOS 13 Device.
Crash not happens when app builds prior to Xcode11 and install in iOS 13 device.

Comment: @PrasathBabu I have not tried on iOS 13, but I just tried on iOS 13.1.3 and I have not found a problem on my real device. just freezing on simulator. thats why I have a doubt either to add the code below (answer) or not

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it by using runtime:

add the following code to the bottom of placeholder setting

```
Ivar ivar =  class_getInstanceVariable([UITextField class], "_placeholderLabel");
UILabel *placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, ivar);
placeholderLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

At Xcode 11 beta2 ,this code is work ,but I don't know about GM version or official version.

The complete code:

- Objective-C Version

```c
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.title = @"UITextField Demo";

    UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 50);
    textField.placeholder = @"UITextField Demo";
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    Ivar ivar =  class_getInstanceVariable([UITextField class], "_placeholderLabel");
    UILabel *placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, ivar);

    placeholderLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

@end
```

- Swift Version:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50)
        textField.placeholder = "UITextField Demo"
        view.addSubview(textField)

        let iVar = class_getInstanceVariable(UITextField.self, "_placeholderLabel")!
        let placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, iVar) as! UILabel
        placeholderLabel.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

### 2019/09/25 Update

The above implementation can solve the problem ,but it not be advocated.

The apps that use the private api maybe broken in the future.

Please use new api :

```swift
var attributedPlaceholder: NSAttributedString? { get set }
```

Discussion

> This property is nil by default. If set, the placeholder string is drawn using system-defined color and the remaining style information (except the text color) of the attributed string. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the placeholder property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. Assigning a new value to this property does not affect any other style-related properties of the text field.

The complete code:

```swift
let textField = UITextField()
textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50)
let placeholderString = NSAttributedString.init(string: "UITextField Demo", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red])
textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderString
view.addSubview(textField)
```

Comment: Thanks. This 'bug' still exists in Beta 6. Wrote this in Swift and works there too.

Comment: Why in the world would you recommend people do something that is obviously not allowed by posting another workaround? This is not OK, stop doing it. Your apps will be broken in the future.

Comment: @russbishop any solution how to change it then? Thanks

Comment: @russbishop Thank you for reminding me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @iDevOrz it's clearly written in docs "If set, the placeholder string is drawn using system-defined color and the remaining style information (except the text color)". So you didn't answer the question in your update

Comment: Changing the placeholder text color is not supported by UIKit, but feedback requests for that are appreciated. You can use `attributedPlaceholderString` to change _other_ style attributes of the placeholder text.

Comment: @Mikhail Maslo,Thank you for your remind，But When I build in Xcode 11 and launch in iOS 12.2 and iOS 13 Simulator, This worked for me.How strange this is!

Answer (score 14):

I think it's a bug from the XCode side and hopefully, they will fix this one on the next release. You can quickly fix this by Erase all Contents and Settings on the Simulator device.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes this problem is related with the Xcode version. I have Xcode 11.2.1 and i am facing same issue.

```
_placeholderLabel.textColor
```

if you are using it from storyboard as runtime var and getting issue so just remove "_"

like that
[image]

after removing the "_" runtime Var start working

Answer (score 11):

Remove Underscore "_" and try this.

```
[textfield setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

It should work for all versions!

Comment: This worked for me in simulator and Xcode 11.2.1. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I did it this way :

Objc

```
NSMutableAttributedString *placeholderAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:searchField.attributedPlaceholder];
[placeholderAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeholderAttributedString length])];
searchField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderAttributedString;
```

Swift 5

```
var placeholderAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: searchField.attributedPlaceholder)
    placeholderAttributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: placeholderAttributedString.length))
    searchField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderAttributedString
```

It's a bit long but I have nothing better for the moment.

Comment: Only acceptable answer for now, I am using Xcode 11.0

Comment: Try to Erase all contents and settings on simulator :)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using UITextView+Placeholder.h class please change below method Clean and build if issue persists

Objective C

```
+(UIColor *)defaultPlaceholderColor {

    static UIColor *color = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        textField.placeholder = @" ";
        //        color = [textField valueForKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        Ivar ivar =  class_getInstanceVariable([UITextField class], "_placeholderLabel");
        UILabel *placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, ivar);
        color =  placeholderLabel.textColor;

    });
    return color;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `UITextField` placeholder text color, font using `attributedPlaceholder` method as follows :

```
NSString *text = [textField text];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14.0f]}];
```

Answer (score 2):

"Erase all contents and settings"

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the var "_placeholderLabel" in the section "User Defined Runtime Attributes"
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `_placeholderLabel` with `placeholderLabel`

Answer (score 1):

For IOS 13 you can set UITextField placeholder color by one line code.

**Objective C**

```
[textField setAttributedPlaceholder:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"PlaceHolder Text" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}]];
```

In **Swift 5**

```
txtTitle.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"PlaceHolder Text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 0):

### - Swift Version

Add the following code to the bottom of placeholder setting:

```
    let iVar = class_getInstanceVariable(UITextField.self, "_placeholderLabel")!
    let placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, iVar) as! UILabel

    placeholderLabel.textColor = .white
```

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .gray

    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50)
    textField.placeholder = "UITextField Demo"
    view.addSubview(textField)
    let iVar = class_getInstanceVariable(UITextField.self, "_placeholderLabel")!
    let placeholderLabel = object_getIvar(textField, iVar) as! UILabel

    placeholderLabel.textColor = .white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Here is a correct Swift replacement of that property.
Note that if you also change alignment of other properties for the text field, then you need to set these properties to placeholder's attributed text too. Usually only color and font are changed:

```
/// Set placeholder text color
/// - Parameter color: the color
func setPlaceholderColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    // Color
    var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: color]
    var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)

    // Font
    if let text = attributedText, text.length > 0, let attrs = attributedText?.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &range), let font = attrs[.font] {
        attributes[.font] = font
    }
    else if let font = font {
        attributes[.font] = font
    }
    self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "", attributes: attributes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **FOR UISEARCHBAR PLACEHOLDER** COLOR

**`Xcode 11.1`**

From iOS 13 onwards the SDK provides **UISearchBar.searchTextField** so we can use 
 public API instead of private API. In the subclass of ***UISearchBar*** i have used this code to change the placeholder color

```
UITextField *textField = [self findSubviewOfClass:[UITextField class]];
textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Regular" size:14.0f];

if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    self.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.82 blue:0.81 alpha:1]}];

}else {
    [textField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.82 blue:0.81 alpha:1] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "_" form "_placeholderLabel.textColor" try with "placeholderLabel.textColor".