# iOS 13: Change UITextField "_placeholderLabel" property

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have an application that uses "_placeholderLabel" UITextField property and changes to UILabel adjust UILabel Font size according to the given width. I am attaching below code that works for all iOS lower than 13 but for iOS 13 it crashing while fetching the **_placeholderLabel** property.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) 
{
/// iOS 13 code for adjust fonts
} else {
 (txtSearchField.value(forKey: "_placeholderLabel") as! UILabel).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
}
```

Comment: you can directly call `txtSearchField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Comment: see this for help :[Xcode 11 Beta - iOS 13 Simulator - UITextField with Placeholder getting app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526966/xcode-11-beta-ios-13-simulator-uitextfield-with-placeholder-getting-app-cras)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks!! I use Ivar solution, that works for me.